# Is Pentaho ETL tool dying?

Tags: etl, pentaho

I have problems finding useful pentaho ETL tool information, is this tool dying?
What are the alternative tools/platform>

Answer (score 5):

In short, yes, Hitachi Vantara aquired the suite and they aren't giving much love to it. They've just released the 9.2 version, but I don't have much faith in having a lot of improvements for the CE version, maybe some more for the paid version, but I don't think there's going to be much either, they killed the old forum and the new community they created is deserted.

For the Data Integration (ETL) part of the suite, you can go to apache-hop (https://hop.apache.org). A bunch of Kettle (the original name for the Pentaho Data Integration tool of Pentaho Suite) developers are actively modernizing and much improving the old code: it mostly works with Java 11, they are staying in Java 8 because of dependencies of the Beam plugins, the dependencies with old deprecated libraries are gone, for now there's not a lot of new functionality, just migration with some new features, but even if there isn't a 1.0 version yet, it is much advanced and some PDI/Kettle users are beginning to transition their production environment to this new tool.

There's a migration utility for the old jobs and transformations in PDI to workflows and pipelines in Hop. After applying the migration tool you're going to need to check and modify things yet, DB connections are possibly going to need some work afterwards, and a few of the old steps aren't available in Hop (Formula step is the one that most affect me) but in general the utility saves a lot of work.

New things in Hop:

- Built with the idea of supporting project and environment configuration, so paths and information that are project/machine dependent work with different configurations, you just change the project or environment information and everything works.
- Much better metadata injection support, PDI/Kettle still had a lot of steps with properties not available for metadata injection, and in the migration they have added it
- Night mode
- Much lighter, quicker start (PDI takes a long time just to initialize) and you can get rid of steps/plugins that you don't need if you just need a thin client to perform one task.
- Hop-web